# when i click it's the last possible value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, for-loop

before everything, ty for helping and sorry for the noob question.

I have problem with event inside a for. The DOM is something like that:

```
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="trigger">...</div>
  <div class="trigger">...</div>

  <div class="box">...</div>
  <div class="box">...</div>

</div>
```

And my JS jQuery is:

```
for( i = 0; i < $('.trigger').length; i++ ){
$('.trigger:eq('+i+')').click(function(){
    $('.box:eq('+i+')').fadeIn();
});

$('.box:eq('+i+') .bt-close').click(function(){
    $('.box:eq('+i+')').fadeOut();
});
}
```

Well, the problem is, when i click on trigger, the value of i is 2. I don't want to use trigger1, trigger2... because i do not know how many will have in the final version.

Comment: Popular question asked in a different form. i is referenced, not assigned.

Comment: d2dbr could you state a clear question? I don't even know what the question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function createEffects(index) {
    $('.trigger:eq(' + index + ')').click(function() {
        $('.box:eq(' + index + ')').fadeIn();
    });

    $('.box:eq(' + index + ')').click(function() {
        $('.box:eq(' + index + ')').fadeOut();
    });
}


for (i = 0; i < $('.trigger').length; i++) {

    createEffects(i);
}​
```

I would avoid using closures when you can. Here's an example without them: http://jsfiddle.net/JBbQk/

Comment: Just curious, could you explain what the difference is between calling the function from the for loop vs just having the function contents inside the for loop?

Comment: As the loop progresses, each click event is still pointing to the same variable `i`.  Since the click events will be firing after the loop has finished, they will all point to the last value that was stored in i.

When you wrap your logic in a function, you are creating a new copy of `i` for each function to reference that captures the current value of `i`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now it works and the solution is simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in closures. The function inside the loop will remember the variable `i` from the scope around it, and not its value. When the function gets called, the loop would have already exited, and the variable value is the last one. Instead, make the functions get the value itself. The usual way to do it is by using another variable. One way to do it is as @JoeTuskan shows. Another is by using a self-executing anonymous function:

```
for( i = 0; i < $('.trigger').length; i++ ){
  (function(j) {
    $('.trigger:eq('+j+')').click(function(){
      $('.box:eq('+j+')').fadeIn();
    });

    $('.box:eq('+j+') .bt-close').click(function(){
      $('.box:eq('+j+')').fadeOut();
    });
  })(i);
}
```

The difference here is that the outer anonymous function (the one immediately wrapping the loop contents) does not access the loop variable at all, and therefore does not capture it. It is instead being called with a parameter whose value doesn't change within the function, which is then captured by the inner functions.

It's not quite that you mustn't create functions within loops; but that if you do, you want to have a closure that captures the loop variable between them and the loop. Whether the function that creates that closure is externally defined, as in @JoeTuskan's example, or internal, as in mine, is a matter of style; as long as you understand why it works as it does. Actually the way explained in his post should be a bit faster than this one, since this way you keep creating N anonymous functions, but I believe it might be easier to understand what is actually happening this way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this behaviour, is that those `function(){...}` are the closures. In short, when you create a closure, javascript interpreter copies the environment at the point of function declaration, thus allowing function accessing them, even if they are out of scope (and would be garbage-collected without closure).

You have faced one possible drawback of this: the closures **does not** receive copies of objects, they just have the access to the variables. Consider an example:

```
var i=0;
var closure = function() {alert(i);}
closure(); //alerts 0
i=1;
closure(); //alerts 1;
```

The same happens in your example. The for-loop runs to the end, leaving `i` with `$('.trigger').length` value.

So, the proper way of achieving what you want is [Joe Tuskan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10075303/882918)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using each:

```
var triggers = $('.trigger');
var boxes = $('.box');
triggers.each(
    function( ind ){
        var box = boxes.eq(ind);
        $(this).on("click", 
            function(){
                box.fadeIn();
            }
        );
    }
);

boxes.find(".bt-close").on("click", 
    function(){
        $(this).closest('.box').fadeOut(); //might be better to use parents(".box") - depends on HTML
    }
);
```